# Como acceder al valor read del pureComputed

Tags: javascript, html5, knockoutjs

Me gustaría saber cómo llamo a la función read. Cuando escribo en `value: valueView` llama a la función write pero quiero que al final de la función haga una llamada a read. Existe algún método para avisar a read?

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: valueView" placeholder="VALOR">

    self.valueView = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            var value = “John”;
            return value;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            callRead() ¿???
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes invocar directamente el nombre del observable y esto te dará el valor (o básicamente invocará a su funcion `get`):

Si tu *pureComputed* se llama `valueView` invocar `self.valueView()` retornará `'John'`.

Edita el valor del input y verás como imprime su valor en la consola.

```js
function App() {
  var self = this;
  self.valueView = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      var value = 'John';
      console.log('read called');
      return value;
    },
    write: function(value) {
      console.log('>> get value:', self.valueView());
      console.log('passed value:', value);
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: valueView" placeholder="VALOR">
</div>
```

Fíjate que estás usando un *pure computed observable* así que debes tener mucho cuidado de no modificar estado cuando implementes su método `write`. Siempre debes tener en cuenta que:

> 1. Evaluar el *computed observable* no causa ningún efecto secundario.
> 2. El valor del *computed observable* no cambia basandose en el número de evaluaciones o alguna otra información oculta. Su valor debe basarse solamente en los valores de otros observables en la aplicación, los cuales para la definición de función pura, son considerados sus parámetros.

**Update**

Aquí te pongo ejemplo de los casos usuales que **NO** se deben hacer cuando trabajas con *pureComputed* basandose en los puntos anteriores

1. Efectos secundarios al evaluar el *pureComputed*

```js
function App() {
  var self = this;
  self.otroValor = 0;
  self.valueView = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      // ***** Muy mala idea ******
      // No se deben modificar valores en la fase de evaluación
      self.otroValor++;
      // No se deben hacer llamadas en la evaluación
      self.update();
      // No se debe intentar actualizar el elemento actual
      return 'John';
    }
  });

  self.update = function() {
    // actualizacion de estado, llamadas al servidor, etc
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: valueView" placeholder="VALOR">
```

La razón de esto es que cuando un *pureComputed* no tiene ningun subscriptor se encuentra **durmiendo** por lo que el código no se ejecuta. Para ese tipo de funcionalidad debes usar otro tipo de observables.

Comment: Hola devconcept gracias es una solución que he intentado pero en mi proyecto me sigue sin funcionar. De momento como provisional he creado una variable auxiliar que esta en read y write, cuando estoy en write hago un set de la variable auxiliar situada dentro de read...

Comment: @gvivetapplus Si no te funciona es porque probablemente estás violando uno de los dos principios. Si lees más detenidamente el 2 verás que especifican que siempre debes basarte en otros observables para manipular los valores. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el ejemplo completo o abre una nueva pregunta y pon un fragmento de código que permita reproducirlo. La respuesta que pides en tu pregunta fue la que te puse en mi respuesta. "Como acceder al valor read del *pureComputed*"

Comment: Seria mucho pedir poner un ejemplo de una violación. Me cuesta entender estas definiciones.

Comment: @gvivetapplus Ya actualizé la respuesta